# how to add space of a number after first four one space then after two one space etc using awk

Tags: linux, sed

I want to add multiple spaces of a Number is "`20120911162500`" add space first four then after every two.

Desired output is

```
2012 09 11 16 25 00
```

This is what I tried:

```
echo "2012 09 11 16 25 00" |sed 's/.\{4\}/& /g'
```

but the output is `2012 0911 1625 00`.

Comment: With which tool/language ?

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: yes, but i didn't properly try echo "2012 09 11 16 25 00" |sed 's/.\{4\}/& /g'       output  2012 0911 1625 00

Comment: Is this really the case you are facing? Or are you having something more generic? Because this sounds like a `date` output.

Comment: yes i get input column format is 20120911162500 but i cannot use this format is mktime() function example echo | awk '{print strftime("%d-%m-%Y",mktime("2012 12 21 00 00 00"));}' its output is correct.But echo | awk '{print strftime("%d-%m-%Y",mktime("20121221000000"));}' its output is wrong, can you help me to solve this issue using sed or awk

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/../ &/3g' file
```

This prepends a space to the third pair of characters and every 2 characters thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
echo "20120911162500" |sed 's/.\{2\}/& /g;s/ //'
2012 09 11 16 25 00
```

Add space to every 2 digits `s/.\{2\}/& /g` then remove the first space to make it 4 digits `s/ //'` .

Answer (score 0):

Create a file

**f.awk**

```
function sep(i, n) { # which separator to use?
    if (i==n)        return ""
    if (i<4)         return ""
    if (i % 2 == 0)  return " "
    return ""
}

function format(num,    n, i, ans) {
    n = split(num, a, "")
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
      ans = ans a[i] sep(i, n)
    return ans
}

{
    print format($0)
}
```

Usage:

```
echo 12345678901234 | awk -f f.awk
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the Add Button Click Event

It will be give space first after four digit and then second after two digit space and so on

For Example

```
string data = TextBox1. Text;
    string[] no = new string[data.Length];
    string number = "";
    int k = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == k)
        {
            number += " ";
            k = k + 2;
        }

        number += data[i] ;
    }
    Label1.Text = number.ToString();
```

Comment: This is off-topic.